# Exception when attempting to connect to database

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

I have a very simple database with a table called score with columns called id, count and GameDate, when I test it from web services (visual studios) it returns false to me rather than true. 
so its not running my query, I cant seem to find anything wrong with it.

Dose anyone know ?

**code**

```
public bool SaveScore(int Score)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=.SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Balloon_Math;Integrated Security=True";
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    string myQuery = "INSERT INTO score(count, GameDate) VALUES (" + Score + ",'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d", culture) + "')";

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first step should be to catch the exception and figure out what it's telling you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stab in the dark, but I'm gonna guess this bit is wrong `Data Source=.SQLEXPRESS` should probably be something like `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` instead

Comment: would that not be .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: That's what I get for not thinking about the answer too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your catch to this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return false;
}
```

Then place a break point on `return false;` and see what the value of `ex` is

Comment: `catch {}` work also without parameter [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment (as Jonesy already had). It is not a solution to the problem, but a step in the right direction.

Comment: @sab669, Maybe, but code doesn't look very good in a comment.  I'm open to suggestions on that front.